# Sending Request Using A Separate Thread

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send an API request to Yelp from my Android application. I got the sample code to send a request in Java from here https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/java

It worked when I ran the script provided in the repository, however, when I added the code to my Android application, I got an error.

Here's my Android app code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    YelpAPI yelp = new YelpAPI(
            getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_key),
            getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_secret),
            getString(R.string.yelp_token),
            getString(R.string.yelp_token_secret));

    String result = yelp.searchForBusinessesByLocation("bar", "San Jose, CA");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

and the stack trace:

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-23 12:50:23.848    E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: PID: 2328
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)                           ...
```

I found similar problems on the Internet, and I figured it was because I couldn't send the request using the main thread. How do I send a request using a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a new thread, you can do it like this:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        YelpAPI yelp = new YelpAPI(
        getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_key),
        getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_secret),
        getString(R.string.yelp_token),
        getString(R.string.yelp_token_secret));

        String result = yelp.searchForBusinessesByLocation("bar", "San Jose, CA");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
 }).start();
```

Information on Android threads can be found at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html